# How to use React.lazy for a component of a module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the npm package called '@toast-ui/react-editor'. It includes a 'Viewer' react component. I could just use:

```
const Viewer = require("@toast-ui/react-editor").Viewer
```

But it increases the bundle size a lot. So I wanted to load it lazily whenever it is needed by using React.lazy. I am going to use it inside component:

```
<Viewer {...props} />
```

But I don't have any clue how to do it.

I tried this way, but didn't work.

```
const Lazy = React.lazy(() => import(require("@toast-ui/react-editor"))).Viewer;
```

I really want to know how to do it.

Comment: you can skip the require inside import

Comment: Can you remove require inside import

Comment: is it working when you remove the require ?

Comment: yes, I did but it didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As `Viewer` is not a default component, it's not as simple as removing `require`, (which is not even needed, though).

You need to import it dynamically and then return the module as a default one ([as that's what `lazy` expects and works with only](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)).

```
const Viewer = lazy(() =>
  import("@toast-ui/react-editor").then(module => {
    return { default: module.Viewer };
  })
);
```